# Python can't find any modules, even though they are already installed

Tags: python, module, pip

I'm not sure when this began, but it was recently...

I installed modules via `pip` on CMD, it all went smoothly until I went to IDE and attempted to import them, each time i get the same error

`'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named x'`

I have checked that I have Python in my PATH and have reinstalled with different version with no avail.

Comment: Have you checked that you used the correct pip version to install them. On most systems there are two symlinks of pip pointing to `pip2` and `pip3`, which install packages for `python2` and `python3` respectively. check the outputs of `pip -V` and `python -V` and see if they return the same python version.

Comment: You may have two instances of Python installed, with your modules installed in one path, while your interpreter in the IDE is defined to the other path.

Comment: Some IDEs also use/have their own virtual environments. The packages may installed elsewhere but not in the IDE's environment. Make sure the IDE is pointed to the correct environment or pythonpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to uninstall everything and even delete the folders where the modules are stored and then try to install it again; this happened to me a while ago and that's how I solved it

Comment: alright, ill have a try at that!

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a virtual environment for the current project you are working on using venv https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html and use this virtual environment as a test to see if the modules can be used.

It will only look for modules installed within this environment instead of the root installation of python. This may be an easier way to debug your problem and I think it helps to manage different modules imported for different projects to know exactly what versions are being used.

If you are using python 3 ensure you are using the correct version of pip.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Then you can install venv using:

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
```

To create a new virtual environment called "myenv" based on python3 use the command

```
virtualenv -p python3 myenv
```

You then need to activate the environment so when installing modules and packages through pip it will install them to this virtual environment only. The command to activate the virtual environment is:

```
source myenv/bin/activate
```

Once it is activated the name of the environment you are currently using will appear in brackets on your terminal prompt something like this:

```
(myenv) [server]:$
```

Now you can start installing modules using pip3 for this environment

```
(myenv) [server]:$ pip3 install <module>
```

Now you should be able to run python scripts using the version of python from this environment with the packages from this environment.

```
(myenv) [server]:$ python main.py
```

You could also put the shebang line at the top of the scripts so you dont even need use the command python, it will be evaluated for the default version of python for the current environment. Inside the main.py would look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import <module>
```

Then to run the script

```
(myenv) [server]:$ ./main.py
```

I hope this helps, try it out and let me know if you have any problems.